# How to get all dependency project's assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

Im using .Net6 with Visual Studio. I have an executable project(have `main()`) , and it references some library projects, they are all in a VS solution. Now I want to get their's assembly:

```
Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

It works but `assemblies` have about 200 items, I just want to get the assemblies that have the main project and the dependencies project:

```
Assembly mainAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
Assembly[] dependencyAssemblies = mainAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();
```

It takes about 30 items(also have some external lib), and if some projects were not be calling in main project, they will not include in the array too.

I noticed that `bin/xxx.deps.json` have some code after solution built:

```json
{
  ...
  "targets": {
    ".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0": {
      "xxx/1.0.0": {
        "dependencies": {
          "a": "1.0.0",
          "b": "1.0.0",
          "c": "1.0.0"
        }
      ...
}
```

`xxx` and `a b c` is the projects name what I want, how can I get them in the program?

Comment: Did you tried with `AssemblyDependencyResolver`?

Comment: @Tyler Thanks, I tried this, but it also could not tell me wether the assembly is my library project(`resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath()` always return not null).

Comment: Try this `var MyRefs = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();`

Comment: @Tyler  `GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()`'s result are similar of `GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()`.